# Comparing ballot data from two consecutive elections

Tags: clustering, pca, elections

I have two datasets of general elections (in a multi-party single-vote system) which I'm trying to analyze.
Each has about 10,000 data points (ballots) with some 30+ features - the main features are the number of votes each party got (let's denote these by $P_i$ for $i=1,...,N_{parties}$ , but I also have features for the number of eligible voters for that ballot (the number of actual valid votes is of course the sum of the per-party counts, so I can also calculate the turnout in each ballot). Ballots each also have a symbol (which is a number but has no numerical meaning).

For a single election, I'm very satisfied with my analysis which is mainly done using PCA (the 10 most significant components explain away about 98% of the variance, the first two about 70%, so plotting everything on the plain of the two first PCs gives a meaningful scatter plot), and K-Means clustering (on the original dataset, before the PCA) which nicely splits up the ballots into different clusters based on the local political makeup of the population in that ballot.

Now I want to move on to comparing the two datasets to see the political change over time.

I have three different problems here, basically. From easy to difficult they are:

1. The set of ballots in the two elections is not identical. Some ballots are new, mainly as a result of breaking up a single ballot to two new ones. But let's just say that without the mapping between old and new ballots the only reasonable thing I can do is to limit my analysis to ballots that existed in both years.
2. The set of parties in the two elections is not identical, some important parties are new (because of a change in the political scene), some old parties simply disappeared/united into new ones, and some are the same but underwent such a big change that comparing them would be somewhat misleading.
3. But the major methodological problem I don't know how to answer is this: even if the set of ballots and the set of parties were the same, how do I separate between the two sets of features - that of the old election and that of the new one, so that the analysis would know how to compare $P_{i_{old}}$ to $P_{i_{new}}$ for every $i$. I can't just do a union of the features of the two elections in one dataset, as the information about which election each feature belongs to will be lost, and even worse: $P_{i_{old}}$ and $P_{i_{new}}$ might even be considered to be rather well-correlated and one of them discarded in any kind of dimensionality reduction on the features. So basically I want to do PCA and clustering as before, but also machine-learn something about the difference between those two datasets (in other words: my dataset is 3-dimensional here, not 2-dimensional).

In short, I'd be grateful for any suggestions how to handle all three problems.

Comment: These are good questions (+1), however, as a fair word of warning, much of the answers (especially to the 1st 2) depend on how your theory (or other relevant competitor theories in your field) think about these issues, & not on some principle dictated by statistical analyses, IMO. This may limit what you can get from CV.

Comment: It's true that #1 and #2 are mainly solved by some manual mappings of ballots to ballots and of old parties to new ones - I don't see a good way around this (but if anyone has a good idea, I'd be happy to hear). #3 though is independent of the previous two questions and has to do with statistical theory, method and practice. This is where I'm looking for help.